# Cordova SQLite last inserted ID shows up as null when inserting

Tags: sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm building a Cordova app that's using the "Brodysoft SQLitePlugin".
When I insert an entry into safe_sex_planner_version and get the last inserted ID using results.insertId, it prints out without a problem. But when I try using that as `foreign key` in `safe_sex_planner_entry` as version_id, it's either not saving, or saving as a null.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Zee

-- code below --

```
createNewVersion: function(questions)
{
    var name = $("#plan-name-container #plan-name").val();
    var last_insert_id = null;

    db.transaction(function(tx){
        var sql = "INSERT INTO safe_sex_planner_version (name) VALUES (?)";
        tx.executeSql(sql, [name], function(tx, results){
            last_insert_id = results.insertId;
            console.log("Last inserted ID: " + last_insert_id);
        }, errorCB);
    }, errorCB, successCB);

    db.transaction(function(tx){
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {        
            question_id = questions[i].value;
            var answer = $("#planner-items #question-" + question_id).find(".answer-field").val();
            console.log("Answer: " + answer + "-1");

            console.log("Last inserted ID: " + last_insert_id);
            var sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO safe_sex_planner_entry (version_id, question_id, answer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            // var sql = "INSERT INTO safe_sex_planner_entry (version_id, question_id, answer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            tx.executeSql(sql,[last_insert_id, question_id, answer], function(tx, res){}, errorCB);
        }

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM safe_sex_planner_entry WHERE version_id=?";
        tx.executeSql(sql, [last_insert_id], function(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            console.log("Length of safe_sex_planner_entry: " + len);

            for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) 
            {
                var record = results.rows.item(i);
                console.log("Safe sex planner ID: " + record.id);
                console.log("Safe sex planner Version ID: " + record.version_id);
                console.log("Safe sex planner Question ID: " + record.question_id);
                console.log("Safe sex planner Answer: " + record.answer);
            }
        });

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM safe_sex_planner_entry";
        tx.executeSql(sql, [], function(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            console.log("Length of safe_sex_planner_entry" + len);
        });

    }, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to have the INSERTs in two different transactions (and functions).

Put everything into a single transaction, and do the insertion of the entries in the success callback of the first insert.